# When change position to fixed it losses his justify

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a table (with divs). When changing the header to position fixed (dont want to hide header when there are more data and scrolls) it moves all header-cels to the right. I tried to change margin-left to any header-cell to moving at his right position. (repositioning)

The problem is, that when trying to resize the browser window, header titles and data did not displayed correctly and loose their justify..

How to correct header-cels moving (following) data?

```css
body {width:100%; height:300px; background-color:#1f1e1e; overflow:auto;}

.records {width:99%; height:200px;}

.header-cell {height:20px; width:20%; background:#3a3a3a; color:#fff; display:inline-block; margin-left:0px; margin-bottom:4px; }

.cell {height:20px; width:20%; background:#ccc; display:inline-block; margin-left:0px; margin-top:2px;}
```

```html
<div class="records" >
  <div id="header">
      <div class="header-cell">#</div>
      <div class="header-cell" style="margin-left:-4px;">Name</div>
      <div class="header-cell" style="margin-left:-4px;">Movie</div>
      <div class="header-cell" style="margin-left:-4px;">Episodes</div>   
      <div class="header-cell" style="margin-left:-4px;">Age</div>
  </div>  
  <div id="row1">
      <div class="cell">145</div>
      <div class="cell" style="margin-left:-4px;white-space: nowrap;">J. Snow</div>
      <div class="cell" style="margin-left:-4px;white-space: nowrap;">Game Of Thrones</div>
      <div class="cell" style="margin-left:-4px;white-space: nowrap;">2-3-4-6-11</div>    
      <div class="cell" style="margin-left:-4px;white-space: nowrap;">27</div>
  </div>
  <div id="row2">
      <div class="cell">145</div>
      <div class="cell" style="margin-left:-4px;white-space: nowrap;">J. Snow</div>
      <div class="cell" style="margin-left:-4px;white-space: nowrap;">Game Of Thrones</div>
      <div class="cell" style="margin-left:-4px;white-space: nowrap;">2-3-4-6-11</div>    
      <div class="cell" style="margin-left:-4px;white-space: nowrap;">27</div>
  </div>
  <div id="row3">
      <div class="cell">145</div>
      <div class="cell" style="margin-left:-4px;white-space: nowrap;">J. Snow</div>
      <div class="cell" style="margin-left:-4px;white-space: nowrap;">Game Of Thrones</div>
      <div class="cell" style="margin-left:-4px;white-space: nowrap;">2-3-4-6-11</div>    
      <div class="cell" style="margin-left:-4px;white-space: nowrap;">27</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `position: fixed;` the div loses its width. Set `width` explicitly:

```
.header {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
}
```

**Updated snippet:**

```css
body {width:100%; height:300px; background-color:#1f1e1e; overflow:auto;}

.records {width:99%; height:200px;}

.header-cell {height:20px; width:20%; background:#3a3a3a; color:#fff; display:inline-block; margin-left:0px; margin-bottom:4px; }

.cell {height:20px; width:20%; background:#ccc; display:inline-block; margin-left:0px; margin-top:2px;}

.header {
    position:fixed;
    width:100%;
}
.row1 {
    padding-top:20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="records" >
  <div id="header" class="header">
      <div class="header-cell">#</div>
      <div class="header-cell" style="margin-left:-4px;">Name</div>
      <div class="header-cell" style="margin-left:-4px;">Movie</div>
      <div class="header-cell" style="margin-left:-4px;">Episodes</div>   
      <div class="header-cell" style="margin-left:-4px;">Age</div>
  </div>  
  <div id="row1" class="row1">
      <div class="cell">145</div>
      <div class="cell" style="margin-left:-4px;white-space: nowrap;">J. Snow</div>
      <div class="cell" style="margin-left:-4px;white-space: nowrap;">Game Of Thrones</div>
      <div class="cell" style="margin-left:-4px;white-space: nowrap;">2-3-4-6-11</div>    
      <div class="cell" style="margin-left:-4px;white-space: nowrap;">27</div>
  </div>
  <div id="row2">
      <div class="cell">145</div>
      <div class="cell" style="margin-left:-4px;white-space: nowrap;">J. Snow</div>
      <div class="cell" style="margin-left:-4px;white-space: nowrap;">Game Of Thrones</div>
      <div class="cell" style="margin-left:-4px;white-space: nowrap;">2-3-4-6-11</div>    
      <div class="cell" style="margin-left:-4px;white-space: nowrap;">27</div>
  </div>
  <div id="row3">
      <div class="cell">145</div>
      <div class="cell" style="margin-left:-4px;white-space: nowrap;">J. Snow</div>
      <div class="cell" style="margin-left:-4px;white-space: nowrap;">Game Of Thrones</div>
      <div class="cell" style="margin-left:-4px;white-space: nowrap;">2-3-4-6-11</div>    
      <div class="cell" style="margin-left:-4px;white-space: nowrap;">27</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: When resizing browser window the header cell does not follow the rows...

Comment: When you resize the snippet I posted in the answer the header cells do not follow to rows? Or the snippet work but when you use it in another place it doesnt work? You should see this in the snippet.... what browser are you using?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/snart1/tkn2v561/2/ resize the display window in this fiddle  ..
The header cels does not follow the data cels....

Comment: Tested it in fiddle and working perfect...

Thnak you soooooo much Jaqen ;)